# Adding an entire array to a linked list

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

Hello everybody I have a question regarding adding an entire array to a linked list and what I mean by that is not adding the values with an `int` array to a linked list but to store the array itself within the linked list. For example

```
int[] numbers = new int[1,2,3];
LinkedList<something> hi = new LinkedList<something>();
hi.add(array);
```

This is what I would like to do as I want to store a copy of numbers and than change numbers. I do this so I can compare the past version of numbers with the current one. The reason I want to compare the past and current is so when I change numbers I make sure not to change it to a past version of numbers and always generating a unique state. So I have two questions one how do I store  a full array into a linked list or is there better way to keep track variation of numbers I created.

Comment: The linked list type is the easier part: `LinkedList<int[]> hi = new LinkedList<>()`. But for keeping track of changes, you don't have a built-in solution. You'll have to build your own. It's even harder as it's the array that you'll be changing; so you may need to wrap it in a class that encapsulates it and records changes made through a method.

Comment: Oh when I tried the int[] type i got an error before but I tried it again and works. I love coding